# SQL Server 2008 sudden high IO Stall and queries dead in water

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, io

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise SP4 0.0.6547.0 x64
Running on Windows 2012R2 patched current.
A VM running on Cisco UCM blades and 6.0 Update 3 plus patches.
A Nimble CS700 SAN for the storage.

This is a large OLTP server with 12 vCPU. Normal CPU usage hovers around 6-11%

What happens is that, without warning, the IO Stall times will go through the roof (2000-1000ms) and most queries will stop returning results.  Adam Machanic's sp_whoisactive will show dozens of active queries. CPU is at 90+%.

SAN shows almost zero activity and all other VMs on the same SAN are operating optimally.

We see massive blocking as the stalled processes hold blocks, with some timing out and sleeping with blocks hanging on the SPID.  Killing the SPIDs in question provides temporary relief, but seconds later we are right back where we started.

The **only** thing that provides relief is a reboot of the server.

Management is rightly demanding an actual root cause.  When this happened last summer, with visibility to the CEO level, we engaged Microsoft support, who were dumbfounded and offered no actual root cause.

What I can't do is upgrade the SQL server.  The machine hosts a packaged application and the package publisher refuses to support their software if we implement any newer SQL Server version.  I desperately want to go to 2014/2016/2017, and would feel that it would solve this problem and others.

In any event, I searched the bug reports and did not see anything that matched.

Has anyone run into this issue?  If so did you suss out a root cause?  I have a gut feel that there is a bug in either SQL 2008, Windows 2012R2 or how they interact.  But I don't want to write that into the RCA without having some corroboration.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: So, you are on the right track it seems. You have some queries which are blocking each other and / or causing some high waits that isn't related to your SAN, or so it sounds from the post. I'd personally start with [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) and if it is query related, [sp_BlitzCache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/). Make sure you don't have two resource intensive jobs running in parallel like CHECKDB and a REINDEX or something.Simply restarting the SQL Service would probably do the same as the server reboot, but this doesn't fix the core problem you'll find

Comment: At the time of the problem, no index reorgs or rebuilds were running.  Nor was any checkDB or backup running.  Since there was a reboot, we'd have to wait to see the incident repeat in order to use the sp_blitz... toolset.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research pointed to VMWare.  The machine was allocated 304GB of RAM, 264GB of which was assigned to SQL Server.  However the underlying host was overcommitted on RAM by a large amount.  We suspect thrashing as page life drops, and as other VMs also need real RAM.

Thanks
John.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

1.) Try eliminate storage issues.We once had a storage issue(SAN) and root cause seemed to be some [HBA](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/feature/HBAs-explained).You can further check if your storage is performing with in acceptable limits

You should start with below counters and see if they are less than 15ms

> Avg. Disk sec/Read - is the average time, in seconds, of a read of data from the disk.
>   Avg. Disk sec/Write - is the average time, in seconds, of a write of data to the disk.

There is more info here  :https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2460/perfmon-counters-to-identify-sql-server-disk-bottlenecks/

2.) Once you have eliminated storage issues, you can further check if SQLSERVER is the only causing IO spikes or if there are any other applications causing IO.You can use resource monitor to find this

3.) If you have reached here, SQLSERVER may be culprit..Go with below steps and try following same sequence and  see if problem persists after each step.

Remember HIGH IO can be caused due to

- Stale stats and missing indexes:You might not be updating stats regularly or some type of queries might need more frequent index rebuilds/stats update
- gather queries causing HIGH IO and try tuning them,you can observe number of reads done and try adding indexes to minimize number of reads
- Further Check memory pressure,some times high memory usage can cause Buffer pool flush and there by queries will go to disk..You can look for a counter called `PLE` and see what is good for your environment

Comment: Hi.  
PLE is normally around 40-45 minutes; it does not move much.  The IO velocity is *not* high.  the IO **waits** are high.  We have analyzed the SAN traffic and it is minimal.  SQL itself is making very few IO requests and the SAN is servicing them rapidly.

Stats and indexes are reorganized/rebuilt nightly.  

The long IO stalls - the measurements you mention -- are ONLY on the SQL Server side.  Again the SAN reports almost no traffic.

Comment: What is the value, you will need to check based on some factors:https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-what-queries-in-the-plan-cache-use-a-specific-index/

Comment: I know Jonathan's work.  PLE is in the 40-45 minutes range.  Using his formula I should be treating anything under 5 1/2 HOURS as a poor PLE.  In order to get there, I would need 1.3 TERABYTES of RAM.  

I need to make it clear that there is no extraordinary query traffic when we are beset by this.  It happens without warning.

Comment: Did you try the steps i outlined

Comment: Yes!  Before I wrote the initial note!